# how to clear the lastlog file without interruption

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, logs

on our rhel machine ( production server ) we noticed that lastlog is huge

we not want to interrupt the OS logs that always wrote to log
but we want to clear the lastlog

is it ok to clear the lastlog as

```
echo > /var/log/lastlog
```

second

how is it possible to disable writing to lastlog as permanent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lastlog does not report its size correctly in `ls` and is often not very large at all. If you are checking its size make sure to either run `ls -s` or use `du`.

I believe lastlog is what is called a [sparse file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file). `ls` without the `-s` flag is reporting the apparent size of the file instead of the actual size.

Most likely you do not need to clear lastlog or be concerned with how much it is being written to at all.

Comment: the size is 11G ( from du )

Comment: so we need to do it something - can you approve the approach as echo > /var/log/lastlog

Comment: lastlog is a binary file that contains information about the last time a user logged in, I would always recommend copying the file to a partition that has more storage and compressing it prior to clearing it. However, If you are sure you do not need/want that information I do not think you will introduce any problems by `echo > /var/log/lastlog` to clear it out.

Answer (score 1):

Overwriting lastlog on RHEL 7 does NOT clear it, but replaces the info when you reboot.

I don't care that the size is reported weird, I just want to truly clear it and start over after I clone a VM image to create a new system.

So i tried output redirection '>' to overwite it before a reboo.
Then I tried to rename it and reboot, but it creates it again with all the history.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way:

```
~] cat /dev/null > /var/log/lastlog
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in addition to Natolio's answer.

It is possible to reset the lastlog for an individual user:

```
sudo lastlog --clear --user username
```

Username can also be a range of users, according to the manpage:

> The users can be specified by a login name, a numerical user ID, or a
> RANGE of users. This RANGE of users can be specified with    a min and
> max values (UID_MIN-UID_MAX), a max value (-UID_MAX), or a min value
> (UID_MIN-).

The following command should clear the lastlog for all regular users:

```
sudo lastlog --clear --user 1000-
```